# How to run bash function in "watch" command?

Tags: bash, watch

Say I have a function f defined in my bashrc

```
function f() {
  date
}
```

I want to run following command to monitor the output
`watch f`.
The command failed with "**sh: f: command not found**".
`watch bash -c f` gives the same.

How to get this watch command working as intended?

Answer (score 5):

`watch` is an external program that starts a new program every time interval.

In your case, neither the started default shell `sh` nor the explicitly started `bash` can know about your function `f` – it's not being passed to them.

You include the function definition in what you run. For example, you could write

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function f() {
  date
}
f
```

into a text file "myscript.sh", make it executable and run it with `watch ./myscript.sh`.

Alternatively, you could also

```bash
function f () {
…
}
typeset -fx f
#   ^---------- modify the type of a name
#        ^----- work only on functions
#         ^---- export to environment
watch -x bash -c "f"
#     ^-------- use `exec` rather than `system` to start bash;
#               makes no sense to start a shell from a shell you
#               only start to start a shell (but omitting -x has
#               no downside other than launching an unnecessary
#               middle layer of `sh`)
```

to export the function declaration to an environment variable and thus make it known to bash as launched from `watch`, as subprocesses inherit environment variables.

I'd recommend you go with the script option - less confusing, and it doesn't mess with the environment, which might have surprising side effects. It has no performance benefits: in both cases, the shell parses the source code of your function declaration in the new subshell.

Lastly, you could do without `watch`:

```bash
while true ; do
  tput clear # to clear the screen
  f
  sleep 1
done
```

`tput clear` will clear the scroll buffer; if you had anything on that previously, you might want to save it before.

Comment: It is VERY BAD ADVICE suggesting to use `tput clear` to "clear the screen" because you didn't also note that it clears the terminal's ***SCROLL BUFFER*** - which destroys any history a user was planning to capture from the scroll buffer.

Comment: Hi @FKEinternet, they said they want to *monitor* the output of f, which I take as "they want to look at it right now, and not the history". If you think of what monitoring actually means, you'll find yourself thinking of people looking at warning lamps and gauges in for example a power plant control room - and not at the log of the last few hours of gauge readings. Feels to me like relying on a scroll back buffer is generally not optimal.

Comment: Still, I'm very thankful for the improvement of my answer and the warning is fair. I shortened your proposed wording a bit and took it. Thanks!

Comment: @FKEinternet you can run `clear` or press Ctrl+L to clear the screen without messing up the scroll history

Comment: @FKEinternet thinking about that, `tput clear` might have the less-invasive effect of just clearing the current screen, at the expense of risking that setting from before survive.

Comment: I use the scroll buffer to capture the history of what commands I have run, and their output.  In this instance, I lost 3 days of documentation of what I had done preparing for and running critical demos - because I wanted to implement a tool to display the number of files in 40 directories on one continuously updated screen.  `watch` did not erase that data, `tput clear` did.

Comment: `watch` also *does not clear the screen*, it merely repositions the cursor at the upper left corner of the screen and redraws the contents on top of the previous output.  I first went back to my `watch` implementation because that screen clearing operation made it impossible to see the data changes that were occurring:  I only wanted to reposition the cursor so I could *overwrite what was on the screen*.  It was after going back to `watch` that I discovered the scroll buffer's contents had been destroyed by executing `tput clear`.